# Apache Ignite Continuous Query

Tags: ignite

Are Continuous Queries executed in a multi-threaded mode or just a single thread?  I am trying to find out what the performance implications are when a millions of entries are added to a cache for which ContinuousQuery is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Well, both - depends on what you mean by "multi-threaded". Query's remote filter is executed by the same thread that performs the cache update, but the updates themselves are generally performed in multiple threads.

On the performance considerations: calling filters and listeners is relatively fast and having a continuous query should not slow down your application, but make sure not to put heavy code into them and not to acquire locks or use transactions to avoid deadlocks.